# I'm moving from C to C++ and I don't get this creation of a class

Tags: c++, class

I'm a C developer and I decided to move to c++ as main language to enlarge my horizons. Studying from "The C++ Programming Language" I saw this example of the creation of a class:

```
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} { }
    double& operator[](int i) { return elem[i]; }
    int size() { return sz; }
private:
    double* elem;
    int sz; 
};
```

And I don't get the use of
    sz{s} { }

Why do we use the `{}`? Why there is not `;` at the end of the line?

Comment: `elem{new double[s]}, sz{s}` is the constructor initializer list, specifying initial values for class data members. `{}` is the constructor's body, which happens to be empty here. As to the semicolon - you don't put semicolons at the end of a function definition in C either, so I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of your confusion.

Comment: Sorry for downvote. I don't understand who did this.

Comment: Doesn't the book have an explanation for this example?

Comment: is it "The C++ Programmi Language" or maybe "The C++ Programming Language" ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I didn't get the {}; thing because I didn't understood that it was a function definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of lazy indentation.
Let's write it clearer:

```
class Vector
{
private:
    double* elem;
    int sz; 
public:
     Vector(int s)
         : elem{new double[s]}
         , sz{s}
     {
         // ctor body
     }

     // More class members
};
```

See? Your mysterious `{}` are just the body of the constructor, that is just a function body, and as in C, functions do not end with a `;`.

The weird lines beginning with  `:` is the *initialization list*, where member variables and base classes are initialized, that is where you write the areguments to their constructors. The `sz{s}` is just the second element in this list.

Answer (score 4):

The last `{}` is the body of the constructor. Methods dont need a `;` at the end.
The stuff before is the initializer list:

```
Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} { }
            // ^^ initializer list        ^^ body of the constructor
```

This could also be written as

```
Vector(int s) {                 // no initializer list, but still 
                                // members are initialized here already
    elem = new double[s];
    sz = s;
}                               // no ; here  !!
```

but then the member are initialized and then assigned a value.