# Pointer in self created Vector class in c++(explanation of code)

Tags: c++

Suppose we have created Vector class:

```
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} { } 
    double& operator[](int i) { return elem[i]; } subscripting
    int size() { return sz; }
private:
    double∗ elem; 
    int sz; 
};
```

What in this code is not clear is this: `elem{new double[s]}` and in particular: why do we put here `[]` sign? What does it mean in this context?

Comment: How else do you plan on allocating an array?

Comment: Ask yourself what `new double[s]` means outside of a self-created vector class.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) and [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Braces are used by several types of initializations since c++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza new function returns the adress of the double type variable. In our case it allocates the adress of the array with size s. It means, that we used square brackets in order to tell compiler, that the size of vector is s?

Comment: not a dupe, but same code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890068/im-moving-from-c-to-c-and-i-dont-get-this-creation-of-a-class/47890156#47890156 ...maybe you should ask you teacher to provide better explanations, not only the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What in this code is not clear is this: elem{new double[s]}

This means that on declaration of an object of `class Vector`, the constructor will allocate a `double` array and assign the address of that memory block to `elem` data member of that instance.
The '{ }' signifies member initializer list the constructor above is equivalent to

```
Vector::Vector(int s)
{
    elem = new double[s];
    sz = s;
}
```

> What does it mean in this context?

In this context it means that the `new` operator returns pointer to the first byte of the `s` (value) sized of `double` array allocated in the memory.

ie. if `s` was 5, The `new` operator allocates an equivalent to `double ar[5]` in the heap and return address of the first byte of the array (memory block).

Answer (score 2):

The `[s]` means that you are creating an array that contains `s` objects.

As a side note: you really should give your Vector class a custom destructor that has `delete[] elem` since you're using `new`. Otherwise, you'll have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

So, let review it one-by-one:

```
Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} { }
```

This line means "constructor for class Vector should receive int parameter 's', then allocate an array of doubles of 's' elements, remember the array in 'elem' field and remember the array length in the 'sz' field.

So, '[]' means 'array' and the number inside is the length of the array.

Colon symbol here is so called "initialization list", it initializes every member mentioned here (split by comma), and the initialization order is driven by the order of members as you place them in the class itself (not by their precedence in the initialization list!).